# Choice of solution for Bessel's ODE when $\nu=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Quick question: I was checking a solution for a PDE that went as follows. By variable separation, you find the ODE
$$
\rho^2\,\xi''(\rho)+ \rho\,\xi'(\rho) + \kappa^2\rho^2\,\xi(\rho) = 0
$$
By inspection that is Bessel's equation for $\nu=0$. So far so good. Then, the solution proposes a solution in the form

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\xi(\rho) = A\,J_0(\kappa\rho) + B\,Y_0(\kappa\rho)\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $J_0$ is a Bessel Function of the first kind and $Y_0$ is one of the second kind. I read in *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* that

> (...) a specific choice for a second solution is denoted $Y_ν(x)$ and is called a Bessel function of
>   the second kind.

So, is equation \eqref{eq:1} so because an ODE of second order requires two solutions and those **have** to be $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$? Or is it because $\nu$ has to be zero and no other orthogonal polynomial were available but $Y_\nu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any combination

$$AJ_{0}\left(\kappa\rho\right) + BY_{0}\left(\kappa\rho\right)$$

with $B\neq0$ would be a second solution. Setting $A=0$ is a specific choice.

Comment: I understand $Y_0$ diverges because $\nu$ is an integer. Since I want an analytic solution that would mean $B$ should always be zero, wouldn't it? When solving a Bessel equation must I always propose a linear combination between $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$?

Comment: @condosz The general solution is a linear combination. Now if you impose the requirement that the solution is finite at the origin, you indeed get $B=0$.

Comment: Always a combination between $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$? Or it could also be something like $\sum_i\,J_i$? (I'm sorry but I really must get this right)

Comment: @condosz $J_{\nu}$ and $Y_{\nu}$ are solutions of the ODE $x^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+xy^{\prime}+\left(x^{2}-\nu^{2}\right)y=0$. Note that $\nu$ appears in the equation itself.